# Subtract all numbers in a range from the largest number and sum the differences - SOLVED

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I’m trying to sum the differences between the largest value in a range and all the other values in the range. Then take the second largest value in the range and sum the differences between that value and all the other values, and so on…

For example:

```
SUM(LARGE(A1:A10,1)-LARGE(A1:A10,2),LARGE(A1:A10,1)-LARGE(A1:A10,3),LARGE(A1:A10),1-LARGE(A1:A10,4),…)
```

And then `LARGE,2, LARGE,3, LARGE,4, LARGE,5…`

This method isn’t working properly, not to mention it gets lengthy. I’ve taken a couple of different approaches, but no luck so far. Would anyone here happen to have any suggestions?

EDIT:

Thanks, Rajesh Sinha! That’s exactly what I needed to do! The simplest solution is usually the correct one, yea?

=SUM(IF($A$21:$A$26<LARGE($A$21:$A$26,1),LARGE($A$21:$A$26,1)-$A$21:$A$26,0))

Did exactly what I needed it to do, summed the differences between each value in the range.

Comment: How many numbers do you have? Food for thought example for 10: your Numbers SORTED from largest to smallest in A1 to A10. B2=$A$1-$A2 and copy down to B10 (B10 should be =$A$1-$A10 then). similarly C3=$A$2-$A3 copy down to C10, D4=$A$3-$A4 copy down to D10. See the pattern? Continue to J10=$A$9-$A10. Then sum columns B and higher.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but "sum the differences between the largest value in a range and all the other values in the range" would be `=SUM(LARGE(A1:A10,1)-A1:A10)` which is mathematically equivalent to Σ(max(X) - xi) with xi each value in the set X.

Comment: PS: if you are using an earlier version of Excel, you might need to enter the formula above as an array formula i.e. type the formula then press CTRL SHIFT ENTER

Comment: Hi @James ,, for better justification please edit the post & share some sample data along with expected result, will help us to fix the issue !! Meanwhile U may try this ,, `{=SUM(IF($A$21:$A$26<LARGE($A$21:$A$26,1),LARGE($A$21:$A$26,1)-$A$21:$A$26,0))} ,,, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** ,,, please confirm whether is working or not !!

Comment: Assuming n numbers, with xm denoting m'th largest and dm sum of differences between xm and the "other values", the following possibilities would seem to exist: 1.dm=sum(xm-xi) - sum over i=1 to n, 2. dm=sum(abs(xm-xi)) - sum over i=1 to n, 3. dm=sum(xm-xi) - sum over i=m+1 to n.  Possibilities 2 and 3 are sums of non-negative numbers. Possibility 1. is mathematically equivalent to n*xm - sum(xi) where sum is over i=1 to n. Which possibility is it? One of these or something else?

Comment: Please confirm your Excel version. Is it actually Excel 2010?

Answer (score 0):

the sum of the differences between any one value and each other value can be found via:

(value*COUNT(entire range))-(SUM(entire range)-value)

with this in mind you can amend the SUM function to include criteria by supplanting it with SUMIFS - e.g.:

(value*COUNT(entire range))-(SUMIFS(entire range,entire range,<value)-value)

you can find the second largest value in the range in a few different ways, but try using a combination of SORT() and XLOOKUP() on the whole range

Comment: ,, better [edit] your post & add some sample data along with the generic formula you are suggesting so far,,, will justify the post !!